# How can I upload a file to server, without browser, using go?

Tags: http, go

```
trsp := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
Url := "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
client := &http.Client{Transport: trsp}
request, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", Url, nil)
k, _ := os.Open(nameOfFile)
request.Header.Set("Action", "download"+k.Name())
...
...
client.Do(request)
```

I have server, and I need to upload to server a file. What should I do with request? As I think I shoud write into request.Body and then, from server handle this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need use the `"mime/multipart"`package to make the http body. like this.

http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013/07/01/golang-multipart-file-upload-example/

```
func newfileUploadRequest(uri string, params map[string]string, paramName, path string) (*http.Request, error) {
  file, err := os.Open(path)
  if err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }
  defer file.Close()

  body := &bytes.Buffer{}
  writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
  part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(paramName, filepath.Base(path))
  if err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }
  _, err = io.Copy(part, file)

  for key, val := range params {
      _ = writer.WriteField(key, val)
  }
  err = writer.Close()
  if err != nil {
      return nil, err
  }

  return http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)
}
```